# How to run vimscript from bash, and get the output in a bash script?

Tags: bash, automation, vim

I'd like to run some vimscript from the command line. Specifically I would like to check if Command-T is already installed on my vim instance (and if not, I'd like to install it).

I can run some commands in vim to detect the presence of Command-T, for example `exists("CommandTFlush")` will return 0 if it exists and 2 if it doesn't.

How can I call this function from a bash script, and interpret the result in bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the following commands. Since vim uses ncurses, you can't echo anything but you can read the return code of the vim process. If you exit vim with `:cquit` vim will exit with return code 1, otherwise it will exit with 0. We can use this to determine the success/failure of the function.

Add the following to a file and save it as `check-command-t.vim`:

```
:let cmdt = exists("CommandTFlush")
:if cmdt == 2
    " It's not installed.
    :cquit
:else
    :exit
:endif
```

From bash we want to use `vim -s check-command-t.vim` to tell vim to run all of the commands in a file.

```
if vim -s check-command-t.vim; then
    # The command exited with return code 0; command-T is installed
else
    # not installed
fi
```

Comment: You don't need to prefix the commands in the Vimscript with `:`, and the canonical file extension is `.vim`, not `.vs`.